# how to remove a usestate element from the dom after 30 seconds in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to remove an usestate element from the dom after 30 seconds
Is there a way to do it:

```
let [showComponent, setShowComponent] = useState(false);

const handleClick = () => setShowComponent(!showComponent);
```

and here is my component:

```
<div role="button" className="user-navigation--item" onClick={toggleLogoutMessage}>
    <i className="fas fa-sign-out-alt user--nav--icon"></i>
    {' Logout '}
    {showComponent && <h1>Do you really want to log out</h1>} // remove this element after 30 sec
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. The following is a simplified example that sets the `show` state to `true` initially but then also starts a `setTimeout` that will set it back to `false` after 30 seconds.

```
function Component() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const showMessage = () => {
    setShow(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setShow(false);
    }, 30000);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={showMessage}>Logout</button>
      {show && "Are you sure?"}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use setTimeout to delay your function:

```
setTimeout(function() { your_func(); }, 30000);

let [showComponent, setShowComponent] = useState(false);

const handleClick = () => {
 setTimeout(function() { setShowComponent(prev => !prev ); }, 30000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let [showComponent, setShowComponent] = useState(false);

const handleClick = () => setTimeout(function() { setShowComponent(!showComponent); }, 30000);
```